# Validating SSL Seal in the Browser in Magento with http:// references

Tags: magento, ssl, https

So, one of my developers used a function like this to make a custom navigation for a Magento eCommerce site:

```
<li><a class="about" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('about') ?></a></li>
```

The only problem is it's outputting like:

```
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/about/" rel="nofollow">about</a></li>
```

From what I understand, SSL seals break in the browser if there are both http:// and https:// references.

I'm trying to look for a quick fix to remedy this and would be thrilled if someone has a better way to do this than what's been done.

Cheers!

---

Revised:

Thanks guys,

I think I've narrowed it down to an extenstion that was installed called, Jirafe.

The output code is:

```
<noscript><p><img src="http://data.jirafe.com//piwik.php?idsite=#####" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
```

The php file that I think generates the script is:

```
class Fooman_Jirafe_Model_JirafeTracker extends Piwik_PiwikTracker
{
    protected function sendRequest($url)
    {
        $client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
        $response = $client->request();

        //check server response
        if ($client->getLastResponse()->isError()) {
            throw new Exception($response->getStatus() .' '. $response->getMessage());
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

How would I request the image via SSL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_secure' => true));
```

or

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_forced_secure' => true));
```

to make Magento use the configured `web/secure/base_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a problem with having non-ssl links on a secure web-page, after all you might wish to link to another website that doesn't support ssl traffic. I think perhaps you can confusing this with including non-secure resources on a page. So in your example I don't believe the anchor link is a problem, but if it was an img tag with a src attribute, then it would cause issues, since you are telling the browser to request an insecure link on a secure page.